# php mail function puts email on top of message

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have this function I've been working on it's not complete yet but when a text is sent it puts the email at the top of the message. How do I remove this??

```
<?php

function sendtext($number, $carrier, $message) {
    return mail("$number@$carrier", "", strip_tags($message));
}

function get_carrier($carrier) {
    if($carrier == "Telus") {
        $c = "msg.telus.com";
    } else {
        $c = "txt.unknown.com";
    }

    return $c;
}

$number = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$carrier = "Telus";
$carrier = get_carrier($carrier);
$code = "";

for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $code .= rand(0,9);
}

$message = "This is the secure code you requested: $code";
echo sendtext($number,$carrier,$message);

?>
```

the text is reieved but looks like this

> email@gmail.com
>   This is the secure code you requested: 898657

also as a side thing if anyone can help with the carrier list I would be greatful.

Comment: its probably a 'feature' the carriers gateway. carrier email to sms gateways are not very reliable

Comment: @Dagon is there a more reliable way to send a text??

Comment: [SMS gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway)